# useBlockProps() nests wrapper with class name inside block wrapper in the editor

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, javascript, block-editor, react

I'm trying to add a tailwind class to the block wrapper of a custom block I'm developing.

However, useBlockProps({className: 'h-full'}) generates an additional wrapper with the tailwind class name instead of adding the class to the block wrapper which is what I presumed it does.

I'm not able to figure out if this is expected behaviour from the sparse documentation on this hook. If it is, is there another way I could simply add a class to the block wrapper? If not, where am I going wrong? Code and image of outputted html below.

I should also add that I'm working with a dynamic block so I only need to add the class to the block wrapper in the editor and not on the front end.

```
import { registerBlockType } from "@wordpress/blocks"
import { Button,PanelBody,PanelRow } from "@wordpress/components"
import { InspectorControls,MediaUpload,MediaUploadCheck } from "@wordpress/block-editor"
import { useBlockProps,useInnerBlocksProps,InnerBlocks } from '@wordpress/block-editor';



registerBlockType("custom-cafe-theme/custom-column",{
    title: "Custom Column",
    attributes: {
        imgID: { type: "number" },
        imgUrl: { type: 'string',default: '' },

    },
    edit: EditComponent,
    save: SaveComponent
})

function EditComponent(props) {

    const blockProps = useBlockProps({ className: 'h-full' });
    const innerBlocksProps = useInnerBlocksProps({ className: 'grid gap-8 px-6 py-16' });

    function onImageSelect(image) {
        props.setAttributes({ imgID: image.id,imgUrl: image.url })
    }

    function removeImage() {
        props.setAttributes({ imgID: 0,imgUrl: '' })

    }


    return (
        <>
            <InspectorControls>
                <PanelBody>
                    <PanelRow>
                        <MediaUploadCheck>
                            <MediaUpload onSelect={onImageSelect} value={props.attributes.imgID} render={({ open }) => {
                                return <Button onClick={open}>Upload or Replace Image</Button>
                            }} />
                        </MediaUploadCheck>
                    </PanelRow>
                    <PanelRow>
                        <MediaUploadCheck>
                            <Button onClick={removeImage}>Remove Image</Button>
                        </MediaUploadCheck>
                    </PanelRow>
                </PanelBody>
            </InspectorControls>
            <div {...blockProps}>
                <div className="w-full min-h-[300px] bg-no-repeat bg-cover bg-center grid justify-center items-center text-center md:h-full md:min-h-[400px]" style={{ backgroundImage: `url('${props.attributes.imgUrl}')` }}>
                    <div {...innerBlocksProps}></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

function SaveComponent() {

    return <InnerBlocks.Content />

}
```

[image: outputted html - editor screen]

Comment: your save component is missing the proper usage of the useBlockProps hook, that's not how that hook works, or how the examples in the official docs work either.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I'm having trouble figuring out what the save component should look like for a dynamic block but I'll go back to the docs in case I've missed something.

Comment: when you say "dynamic" what do you mean? Do you mean for a block that isn't rendered in PHP? Do the official docs examples not show it?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-edit-save/#save, likewise https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/nested-blocks-inner-blocks/ were both the first 2 search results

Comment: Dynamic as in I'm using a PHP render callback for the front-end.  And I meant I'm not sure what the save component should look like if I'm using the useBlockProps hook in the edit function - my understanding is that since I only need the class added to the block wrapper in the editor, I don't need to save  the properties in the save function.

Comment: oooh, in that case what you want to do may not be possible, there's zero documentation on how to render inner blocks from PHP because it's generally assumed it's not possible, and little to no tools or help is provided by the API. You're very much neck deep in highly experimental territory. At an absolute minimum though you aren't supposed to have a save component for a server rendered block. If your block is just a container though ( column ) then I don't see the need for PHP rendering, especially when it's a `<div>` with an inline style attribute, this could be simplified to a single `<div>`

Comment: I've actually figured out how to render inner blocks on the PHP side - the issue I'm facing is adding a class to the block wrapper on the editor side. From the docs, I figured I could accomplish that with the useBlockProps hook in the edit function but it's outputting an additional wrapper instead of simply adding the class to the original wrapper. If you have any ideas about how I could add a class to the block wrapper in the editor screen, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I have several ideas. First, something is strange with your output, there is no default block class constructed with wp-block and block name. Legacy compatibility code may be activated because you are not using block.json (try with it) and PHP block registration. You can also try avoiding fragment shortcode and wrap InspectorControls inside outermost block div.

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing that out! block.json fixed the issue and now the default class is appearing too :)

Answer (score 1):

I was bitten by this as well, and it caused me much frustration. I had *exactly* the same nested block duplication problem that you described above.

I was able to solve this issue by specifying an apiVersion for my custom block.

E.g.:

```js
registerBlockType("custom-cafe-theme/custom-column",{
    apiVersion: 2, // or 3
    title: "Custom Column",
    attributes: {
        imgID: { type: "number" },
        imgUrl: { type: 'string',default: '' },

    },
    edit: EditComponent,
    save: SaveComponent
})
```